# How to detect multiple static body in box2d

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have a some issue regarding multiple detection of static bodies.

How can i detect or differentiate multiple static bodies?
In my game i am using tile map and create 3 objects in static body. How can i differentiate each other when collied with player sprite?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2ways.

```
id obj1  = (id)bodyA->GetUserData();

if( ((CCSprite*)obj1).tag == kTagStaticBody1 ) //check ur sprite tag
{

}
```

//OR:  For identification of class

```
id obj1  = (id)bodyA->GetUserData();

if([obj1 isKindOfClass:[MyActor class]])
{

}
```

Comment: Hey Raj i need your help in jumping box2d body. Can you help me??

Comment: @Leena, hey not yet worked with jumping kind b2body..did u try ApplyLinearImpulse ?

Comment: @Leena, here is one jumping box2d game with sample and source, download sample n try..gud one. http://www.raywenderlich.com/7884/how-to-build-a-monkey-jump-game-using-cocos2d-physicseditor-texturepacker-part-2